# Django Class Based view for a profile page

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-profiles

I want to use class based views to build a profile page. Are there any inbuilt views to achieve this. For eg: I have used `auth_views` for login and register.
Django auth.views doesnt contain a profile view. So I decided to create my own using django inbuilts for create update and delete tasks in the profile. Which class based view should I use to achieve this ?

Answer (score 4):

Profile page is nothing more than `DetailView` - only difference is that object is an actual user profile. If you want to display current user detail page, just override `get_object` method and return user from `request.session` (or it's profile if this is different thing in your project).

Comment: if a user is not authenticated, how to redirect him to login page automatically

Comment: @SahalSajjad If you protect a view as [@login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) it will redirect to login ans after login to the desired page. In Class-Based Views, you can protect the [dispatch()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch) method.

Answer (score 0):

Read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#built-in-class-based-generic-views and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#generic-editing-views for generic views details. But for best understading of class based views read source code files in `django.views.generic` package.

Answer (score 0):

From my own little experiment while trying to learn Django (just started)

Code snippet from base.html:

```
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">{{user.username}} Logout   -- </a>
            <a href="{% url 'users:user_detail' user.pk %}">{{user.username}} Profile</a>
        {% else %}
            <a href=="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
        {% endif %}
```

From my views.py

```
class UserDetailView(DetailView):
    model = User   # this is imported from django.contrib.auth.models
    context_object_name = 'user_object'
    template_name = 'users / user_detail.html'
```

From my user_detail.html page: (for above code snippet : The **user** variable is injected by the `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` context processor)

```
{% if user == user_object %}
    <h4>user and object are the same. Welcome {{ user_object }}</h4>
{% endif %}
```